# Linear multistep methods have even order of convergence

Tags: numerical-methods, numerical-optimization, numerical-calculus

A linear multistep method
$$
\sum_{j=0}^n\alpha_jx_{n-j}=h\sum_{i=0}^n\beta_if(x_{n-j},t_{n-j})
$$
is called symmetric, if
$$
\alpha_{n-j}=-\alpha_{j}, \quad \beta_{n-j}=\beta_{j}, \quad j=0,...,n
$$
Now how can one show that the order of convergence for symmetric linear multistep methods is always an even number?

Answer (score 0):

Formulate the order condition for the symmetric test functions $x(t)=(t-nh/2)^m$ to see that the conditions for $m$ even are trivially satisfied due to symmetry.